# "localhost is currently unable to handle the request"

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I just moved my laravel project from my Windows server to my Ubuntu server. When I try to load the app, it says this page isn't working. I would like to ask your assistance with regards to this matter. Thanks[image]

Comment: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-laravel-on-ubuntu-for-apache/

Comment: Hi thanks man it worked

Comment: @RanilJaramillo, haha. you just copy your project and didn't install the local server. take care for details in the future.

Comment: @kris-roofe put it as answer to confirm

Answer (score 5):

For me it was permission issue on storage directory
set the storage directory permission to 0755 recursively

Comment: This allows anyone, including those with malicious intent, to read and write your files. Laravel requires 0755.

Answer (score 4):

Try this steps:

1. open your terminal.
2. move to your project folder.
3. run `php artisan serve`.
4. open your browser and type `127.0.0.1:8000` or `localhost:8000`.

Comment: hi Mohamed in my windows server i change the server.php to index.php and copy the .htaccess from public to my root directory so that i won't run the command serve.. i would like to have the same result as that..

Comment: thats a really terrible idea. You should point your server to the `public/` folder of your project. There is a reason why the index.php is NOT in the root directory because of security reasons.

Comment: so you mean that the best practice for this is to use the php artisan serve command and always make it up in the server, instead of direct browsing to the application, how about if the server restarted can we do a php artisan serve command upon boot?

Comment: When development in local server run that command `php artisan serve` to test everything is working as you want. In server hosting, point your domain to your public folder or use **.htaccess** to run from public with hiding public from url

Answer (score 2):

There might be a permission issue in your laravel project directory.
Because Laravel maintain logs for every action.
Make sure the files and directories inside your laravel project have a 777 or 775 permission.

Answer (score 0):

1. open your terminal.
2. move to your project folder.
3. try this command '**php artisan serve --port=8080** '
4. open with  **127.0.0.1:8080** or **localhost:8080**

Answer (score 0):

Running "composer update" solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check env file:

```
DB_DATABASE=databaseName
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Answer (score -2):

try this url:

```
http://localhost/warehouse/public/index.php/
```

if you need open the path /test

```
http://localhost/warehouse/public/index.php/test
```